# How to join 2 tables in LINQ to Entity?

Tags: c#, linq-to-entities

I have 2 tables.

```
TableA :- ID, Name, Type
TableB :- ID, Name, TableAID
```

I want to Get the result list with the columns that includes TableA.Name, TableB.Name.
I am using Entity Framework. Currently this is how i get data from Table1A.

```
IEnumerable<TableAModel> tableAData = DatabaseContext.FromContext().DatabaseName.TableA.AsEnumerable().Select(tableAData => tableAData.ToModel());
```

I want to create the same list which also includes the TableB.Name so i can have that display in my Grid? Is it possible?

Please let me know how to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this:

```
var db = DatabaseContext.FromContext();
var result = (from a in db.TableA 
              join b in db.TableB on a.ID equals b.TableAID 
              select new {
                  AID = a.ID, 
                  AName = a.Name, 
                  AType = a.Type, 
                  BName = b.Name}).ToList();
```

Ref: [join clause (C# Reference)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb311040.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

A simple search on google has numerous examples.  Here was one off the first page.  [Link](http://blogs.teamb.com/craigstuntz/2010/01/13/38525/)

Answer (score 0):

You want something like this, but I don't know the exact result you want to achieve so it's hard to say precisely.

```
var db = DatabaseContext.FromContext().DatabaseName;
var AllData = from A in db.TableA
              from B in db.TableB
              where A.ID == B.TableAID
              select new {A,B};
var Result = AllData.AsEnumerable().Select(dat=>new{A=dat.A.ToModel(),B=dat.B.ToModel()});
```